# Loop to transpose dynamic ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have rows of data arranged in columns and need to transpose the data to rows.  The columns vary in length, so i need to dynamically select a range, copy, then paste and transpose, then move to the next row with columns of data.  I was able to insert blank rows that equal the number of columns below each set of data.  I.E. If one row has 3 columns populated, there will be 2 blank rows beneath.  I need to go from the top arrangement to the bottom.

```
A   B   C


D   E   

F       
G   H   I


A       
B       
C       
D       
E       
F       
G       
H       
I
```

Comment: I suggest you post the code you used to insert the blank cells. You're much more likely to get help if you show what you have done, and where you get stuck. It's smart even if your code is not well-written, as you might get some tips so that you don't do the same mistakes the next time.

Comment: Show use what you have now, you will not need to copy paste anything, excel has built in functino that will transpose data. for your first row you would need `[A1:A3] = Application.Transpose([A1:B1])`, showing us your code we can better help you. Also before you run your code does your data have random blank rows mixxed in throughout the sheet? or is there never a blank row between rows until you insert one? Or is there always atleast one? Data like this will help us understand your needs better

Answer (score 0):

If you select the entire range of your top arrangement and run the following macro, it will list you data in the desired format below your selection:

```
Sub TransposeLoop()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set Rng = Selection

    For Each cell In Rng
        If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Value = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```